# Spring Cloud Config Server ResourceController does not map request with useDefaultLabel when path contains slashes

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-config-server

I have a simple Spring Cloud Config Server project (using spring-cloud-config-server-4.0.0)

With a default branch property set
`spring.cloud.config.server.git.default-label`

This works without a label:
GET http://localhost:8888/myAppName/myProfiles/test.txt?useDefaultLabel

This does not (path includes slash):
GET http://localhost:8888/myAppName/myProfiles/path/test.txt?useDefaultLabel

Throws the following Exception:

```
RefNotFoundException: Ref path cannot be resolved
...
at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.resource.ResourceController.retrieve(ResourceController.java:107)
```

It resolves to the wrong controller endpoint:

`@GetMapping("/{name}/{profile}/{label}/**")`

instead of

`@GetMapping(value = "/{name}/{profile}/{path:.*}", params = "useDefaultLabel")`

To my understanding this should work because of this change: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/824

I've tried without success:

- Encoding the slash
- Assigning something ("true") to the useDefaultLabel request parameter